# iTextSharp CheckBox into PdfPCell

Tags: c#, itext

I want to create a PDF document. I have created one table with 2 columns. I used to PdfPCell to put my data into the table.

```
PDFWriterEvents epm = new PDFWriterEvents();

writer.PageEvent = epm;

document.Open();

cb = writer.DirectContent;

PdfPTable tableau = new PdfPTable(2);

tableau.WidthPercentage = 100;
BaseFont f = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
int iTailleEcriture = 10;
int r, v, b, a;
r = 205;
v = 32;
b = 101;
a = 64;
BaseColor c = new BaseColor(r, v, b, a);
BaseColor couleurEcriture = new BaseColor(255, 255, 255);
PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Droit", new Font(f, iTailleEcriture, Font.BOLD, couleurEcriture)));
PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Oui / Non", new Font(f, iTailleEcriture, Font.BOLD, couleurEcriture)));
cell1.BackgroundColor = c;
cell2.BackgroundColor = c;
tableau.SetWidths(widths);
cell1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
cell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
cell1.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
cell2.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
tableau.AddCell(cell1);
tableau.AddCell(cell2);
cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(acces.DESCRIPTION, new Font(f, iTailleEcriture)));

RadioCheckField _radioG;
cell2 = new PdfPCell();
_radioG = new RadioCheckField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0), "", "Yes");
_radioG.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK;
_radioG.Checked = d.OUI_NON;
cell2.FixedHeight = 22;
cell2.Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER;
iTextSharp.text.pdf.events.FieldPositioningEvents kid = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.events.FieldPositioningEvents(writer, _radioG.CheckField, "checks");
kid.Padding = 0.5F;
cell2.CellEvent = kid;

cell1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
cell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
cell1.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
cell2.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
tableau.AddCell(cell1);
tableau.AddCell(cell2);
document.Add(tableau);

cb = writer.DirectContent;
```

But this code don't worked correctly. I have all my text but not my checkboxes. Why ?

Comment: You can't use `FieldPositioningEvents` to place radio buttons. That class creates a `TextField` as a child for your radio group. That can never work. You need to write your own cell event if you want to create radio buttons. Use the `IPdfPCellEvent` implementation mentioned in the following questions as inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681722/how-can-i-create-buttons-to-add-to-a-pdf-file-using-itextsharp

Comment: Thank you for your answer but just I want to put a checkbox which is checked or not by my code. There is no user action just I want print.

Comment: And I can't put border width on all checkbox. How can i make that ?